# The Loday-Quillen-Tsygan theorem for topological (Fréchet) algebras

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, topological-vector-spaces, cyclic-homology

In "Additive K-theory" by Tsygan and Feigin, Section 0.4, a statement is given which seems to generalize (cohomological version of) the well-known Loday-Quillen-Tsygan theorem

$$H_{\text{CE}}^\bullet (\mathfrak{gl}(A)) \cong \Lambda^{\bullet} HC^{\bullet -1} (A), $$
with Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology on the left and cyclic cohomology on the right, to $A = C^\infty(M)$ for a smooth manifold $M$ and *continuous* cohomology, saying:

> Speaking somewhat imprecisely, the algebra $H^\bullet_{\text{cont}}(\mathfrak{gl}(A), \mathbb{R})$ is freely generated by the graded space $\bigoplus_{i > 0} L_i$: $$L_i = (\Omega^{i-1}_M / d \Omega^{i-2}_M)^* \oplus H_{i-3}(M, \mathbb{R}) \oplus H_{i-5}(M, \mathbb{R})) \oplus \dots$$

They do not seem to prove this, but only give a reference to "Noncommutative differential geometry" by Connes, which, as far as I can see, does not consider the question of continuous cohomology of $\mathfrak{gl}(A)$. It appears to me that to make this rigorous, a lot of careful consideration of the topological nuances is required, since $A$ is "only" Fréchet, and $\mathfrak{gl}(A) = \varinjlim \mathfrak{gl}_n(A)$ thus is "only" an LF-space -- if one defines $\mathfrak{gl}(A)$ as this direct limit, at least. It is not clear to me that such details can be handwaved away.

Is anyone aware of a reference where this is treated in the necessary detail? Or, perhaps, an argument why handwaving the details away is actually fine?